# How to find API end point for Release Notes field while creating bug via REST API for Azure DevOps Services

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to add a bug via REST API, but I can't find path for release notes field.

I checked official documentation for field list, but there are no info regarding release notes field 
[official documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20item%20types/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Following could should create opertion to insert info into release notes, but the Path is wrong

```
patchDocument.Add(
                new JsonPatchOperation()
                {
                    Operation = Operation.Add,
                    Path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ReleaseNotes",
                    Value = "1"
                }
            );
```

Is there any unofficial documentation, or some library where I can see list of all available API endpoints for fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - yes! - the link that you have in the question is that API. However, that doc is the API reference for **Get Work Item Types** operation which contains just an example modelling the sample response one might get, and not the holistic list.

Before I begin, I'm assuming that **Release Notes** is a Custom-defined field here, as I don't see it in the default [Work item field index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/work-item-field?view=azure-devops).

To know what `path` for this (custom) field might look like, it'd help to execute the [Get Work Item Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20item%20types/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) API for type **bug** within the scope of your project, and look at the response. This is what I got, for example:

[image: Get Work Item Type Bug]

where "dependsOn" is the custom field that I defined in the process used by my Project.

So for creating a bug, I provided the request body in the following format to the [Create Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) API:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample Bug"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Custom.dependsOn",
    "value": "Auth"
  }
]
```

and voila, had a bug created. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Bhargavi,
You're a genius

Comment: Glad I could help! Thank you! :)